# solr fieldtype string or tokenizer

Tags: solr, tokenize, fieldtype

I need to search for a specific field using tokenizers and by string. I'll use tokenizer only if no result were found for the string one. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can index your content in two separate fields, one analysed (e.g. `text_general` field type) and other as a single token (field type `string`).
Then, when you search Solr, you search on both fields but you boost the non-analysed field so that those results come on top.

I used the similar scenario to boost results that have exact match and show partial matches bellow.

Comment: Yes, I did that. But I can't show de analysed results when I found one by single token search. Any idea?

Comment: Take a look at [shingles](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ShingleFilterFactory) (like ngram for tokens).